# How to add a vagrant VM into an existing domain using powershell script during provisioning?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I am trying to add the vagrant virtual machine into an existing domain.I am novice to this topic.Can anyone please explain the ways to achieve it? An example or reference would be really helpful.

Comment: can you detail what you mean by _add the vagrant virtual machine into an existing domain_ vagrant should mainly use for development so it would not be recommended to use a valid domain to reach the VM; instead you can use `test.local` and it has to be managed through your host file

Comment: I am trying to create a server VM using vagrant where i host an asp.net application which requires the machine to join an existing domain (like xxx.xx.xxxxxx.com).I tried to achieve this by writing a simple shell script , which i run during provisioning.Now by running this script the VM joins the specified domain but Vagrant rdp command stops working and gives: WinRM::WinRMAuthorizationError WinRM::WinRMAuthorizationError).But i am able to RDP the VM from host machine with the IP address given in vagrantfile which is config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.2"